# how to getting data from server in android without sending request?

Tags: android, server

How can I send data from server to android app without directly requesting it from android app?

In google Volley we send request to server, then we get response, but this is useless for me at this moment.

I just can get text message from specific number with `BroadcastReceiver`, but I can't get data from server with `BroadcastReceiver`, just can detect have connection or not.

Is there any way that I can send data to android app and get data as notification?

For example server send data to app and app get data when its online, like Viber, Telegram, Whatsaap and same apps.

Answer (score 4):

[GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is probably what you're looking for. There's other services that work quite similarly too. 
GCM of course [still requires an internet connection and a connection to the Google servers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/how-do-push-notifications-work). The data has to be transported to the device *somehow*.

Answer (score 1):

Besides good answers about GCM above, if you need a push notification solution for a working environment **without Internet access**, I suggest **SignalR** of Microsoft, which has already supported Android and Java (you can find out more at [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) and many questions available in StackOverflow).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/) is a nice example of using GCM, exactly for beginner level. And please, read about [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model). It will really help you to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Any server that support Cloud Messaging, [parse.com](https://parse.com) is one of those. It like [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).